# How to retrieve data once a message is received by webSocket in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm now facing a problem and here's what I want:

1. After page is load, show a blank gridPanel implemented by EXT.NET
2. Press a button named "Update" and then connect to WebSocket Server
3. Once receive message from WebSocket server, retrieve list type data and display it on the gridPanel.
4. The websocket client function and display data on gridPanel should be realized by C#

What I have achieved:

1. Show a blank gridPanel
2. Connect to Websocket server after "Update" button is clicked

The problem is:
I can connect and send message to websocket server, and can receive message from websocket server. Also, I can retrieve data after receiving data inside the "ws.OnMessage{}" function. However, the received data cannot be shown on the EXT.NET gridPanel. Is there any solution to this problem?

The package i used for websocket client is "websocket-sharp/", and use "Fleck" as websocket server. (I just implement the client.) Below is my code:

--------------.cs file--------------

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Xsl;
using WebSocketSharp;
using Ext.Net;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class ProblemExample : System.Web.UI.Page
    {    
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }    
        WebSocket ws;

        static DataTable ConvertToDatatable(List<PcsInfo> list)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("TestCode");
            dt.Columns.Add("TestTime");

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                var row = dt.NewRow();
                row["TestCode"] = item.TestCode;
                row["TestTime"] = item.TestTime;
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            return dt;
        }

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //----When the "Update" button is pressed, call Store1_RefreshData function---
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        protected void Store1_RefreshData(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
        {
            //retrieveData();
            ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8181/");
            ws.Connect();
            ws.OnOpen += (senderWS, eWS) => { };

            ws.OnMessage += (senderWS, eWS) =>
            {                
                if (eWS.Type == Opcode.Text)
                {
                    retrieveData(); 
                }
            };
        }
        public void retrieveData()
        {
            List<PcsInfo> list = new List<PcsInfo>();
            list.Add(new PcsInfo { TestCode = "123", TestTime = "456" });

            this.Store1.DataSource = ConvertToDatatable(list);
            this.Store1.DataBind();
        }

        public class PcsInfo
        {
            public string TestCode;
            public string TestTime;
        }
    }
}
```

--------------.aspx file--------------

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ProblemExample.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.ProblemExample" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml.Xsl" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var submitValue = function (grid, hiddenFormat, format) {
        hiddenFormat.setValue(format);
        console.log("format=" + format);
        grid.submitData(false);
    };

    var template = '<span style="color:{0};">{1}</span>';

    var change = function (value) {
        return String.format(template, (value > 0) ? "green" : "red", value);
    };

    var pctChange = function (value) {
        return String.format(template, (value > 0) ? "green" : "red", value + "%");
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <ext:ResourceManager ID="ResourceManager1" runat="server" />
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <ext:Hidden ID="FormatType" runat="server" />
    <ext:GridPanel 
    ID="GridPanel1"
    runat="server" 
    StripeRows="true"
    Title="Fault log" 
    TrackMouseOver="true"
    Width="800" 
    Height="800"
    AutoWidth="True" ForceLayout="True" ForceValidation="True">
    <Store>
        <ext:Store 
            ID="Store1" 
            runat="server"

            >
            <DirectEventConfig IsUpload="true" />
            <Reader>
                <ext:JsonReader>
                    <Fields>
                        <ext:RecordField Name="TestCode" Type="String"/>
                        <ext:RecordField Name="TestTime" Type="String" />
                    </Fields>
                </ext:JsonReader>
            </Reader>
        </ext:Store>
    </Store>
    <TopBar>
        <ext:Toolbar ID="Toolbar1" runat="server">
            <Items>
                <ext:ToolbarFill ID="ToolbarFill1" runat="server" />
                <ext:Button ID="btn_Update_ext" runat="server" Text="Update" Icon="Reload">
                    <DirectEvents>
                        <Click OnEvent="Store1_RefreshData"></Click>
                    </DirectEvents>
                </ext:Button>
            </Items>
        </ext:Toolbar>
    </TopBar>
    <ColumnModel ID="ColumnModel1" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <ext:Column ColumnID="TestCode" Header="TestCode" DataIndex="TestCode" />
            <ext:Column ColumnID="TestTime" Header="TestTime" DataIndex="TestTime" Width="200px" />
        </Columns>
    </ColumnModel>
    <SelectionModel>
        <ext:RowSelectionModel ID="RowSelectionModel1" runat="server" SingleSelect="true" />
    </SelectionModel>
</ext:GridPanel>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

To conclude, my question occurs on the "Store1_RefreshData()" method. When executing with websocket, the retrieveData() method cannot bind data to Store1. But, if i mark all other codes except the "retrieveData()" in "Store1_RefreshData()" method, it works fine.

Could anyone help solve this problem? Thank you!!